# compact centralisers in maximal Kac-Moody groups over finite fields

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Suppose that I want to choose an element of a maximal Kac-Moody group over a finite field which has a compact centraliser. Is there anything known at all about how I can go about choosing such an element?